# Is that possible to create a SSH tunnel with az ssh?

Tags: postgresql, azure, ssh, azure-cli

I need to connect to a Postgresql flexible server in a VNet on Azure.
We have a virtual machine used as a bastion which has network access to the Postgresql database.
I would like my Postgresql client being able to connect from my local machine to the database. It supports ssh tunneling, but I don't want to manage ssh keys for all the developpers.

Is that possible to create a SSH tunnel with `az ssh` ?

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to connect to windows machines using SSH commands**

*Connect to Windows machines using `Az SSH` commands.*

```
az ssh vm -g $myResourceGroup -n $myVM --local-user $myUsername
```

*Network tunnel also to be created for required TCP ports via the SSH connection. Better use case for this is **Remote Desktop** defaults to port **3389**.*

```
az ssh vm -g $myResourceGroup -n $myVM --local-user $myUsername -- -L 3389:localhost:3389
```

***Connect from Azure portal***

1. Go to the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/) to connect to a VM. Search for and select **Virtual machines**.
2. Select the virtual machine from the list.
3. Select **Connect** from the left menu.
4. Select the **SSH** tab. If Virtual Machine has a JIT policy set, you first select the **Request access** button to request access before you can download the RDP file. For more information about the just-in-time policy, see  [Manage virtual machine access using the just in time policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-just-in-time).*

[image]

**1**. Select the virtual machine you want to protect with JIT.*

***2.** In the menu, select **Configuration***

***3.** Under **Just-in-time access**, select **Enable just-in-time**.*

1. By default, just-in-time access for the VM uses these settings:*

**Windows machine**
*RDP port:3389
Maximum allowed access: Three hours
Allowed source IP addresses:Any*

**Linux machines**

*SSH port:22
Maximum allowed access: Three hours
Allowed source IP addresses: Any*

1. To edit any of these values or add more ports to your JIT configuration, use Microsoft Defender for Cloud's just-in-time Page:
2. From Defender for Cloud's menu, select **Just-in-time VM access**.
3. From the **Configured** tab, right-click on the VM to which you want to add a port, and select edit.

[image]

4. Under **JIT VM access configuration**, you can either edit the existing settings of an already protected port or add a new custom port.
5. Once you finish editing the ports, select **Save.**